# Updating api service to typescript - TS2339: Property 'instance' does not exist on type 'Http'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Why does my instance say it does not exist on Http?

Im using my instance to return which type of axios call im going to make- get/post and so on.

```
    constructor(baseURL: string, headers = {}, config = {}, interceptors = null, timeout = 8000) {
    this.instance = axios.create({
        headers,
        timeout,
        baseURL,
        ...config,
    });

    if (interceptors) {
        interceptors.hook(this.instance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Property 'instance' does not exist on type 'Http'

When creating a class in typescript, you need to declare all of the class properties and their types.

```
import axios, {AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig} from "axios";

class Http {
    public instance: AxiosInstance;

    /* ...  */
}
```

You can get around this requirement when you use a body-less constructor to set the constructor arguments as instance variables.  But in this case you are creating a property within the constructor, so you need to declare it at the top level of the class.

#### Object is possibly 'null'

Additionally, you need to declare types for some of your constructor arguments because they cannot be properly inferred.  Basically typescript takes the type of your default value and assumes that the type of the default is the type of the argument.  So `timeout = 8000` is fine because `timeout` is assumed to be `number` (though personally I add the type anyways for consistency).

But `interceptors = null` is going to cause problems because typescript doesn’t know what the type of `interceptors` is supposed to be when it’s not `null`.  It actually assigns the type of `interceptors` as `null`, so even after checking that it exists you'll still get an error `Object is possibly 'null'`.

You probably already have a type for this object somewhere in your code base, but based on this code snippet alone it has to have a property `hook` which can take your instance:

```
interface Interceptors {
    hook( instance: AxiosInstance ): void;
}
```

In order to use `null` as the default value, we have to say that this variable can be either, aka `Interceptors | null`.

For headers and config, these need to be typed to something which axios can accept.  `AxiosRequestConfig` actually says that the headers can be `any`, but let's limit it to a string-keyed object aka [`Record<string, any>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).  For the config we'll just use the `AxiosRequestConfig` type we imported from axios.  We could get fancy and [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) the properties that we are overriding, but it's unnecessary since they are already optional.

A properly typed constructor might look something like

```
    constructor(
        baseURL: string,
        headers: Record<string, any> = {},
        config: AxiosRequestConfig = {},
        interceptors: Interceptors | null = null,
        timeout: number = 8000
    ) {
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZwDRwN5wIIroCSAdmjAiQMYCmWBqaASjQI4CuN5AwhCQGbAA5nAC%20cflAgg4AImSNZAbgCwAKHXASMGlH4JacUjqi0wMaGhzq4tuAAsIEANYAKLeUq0AXPkJpST2oaAEpfADcIYAATVTVRdXUqABsENCsACRgYMGs1OzgwdgAjZOAqOCgaBGi%20ZIBPOA8KYN8GYjIW2jibOyo%20cih2KgsoV16C22K0mgBVJgAZX0GtIQwJyftq6N00XxZ%20qGiAHhWSNcQSeoA%20OABeHFF1-MnbfoFhNv8WDi4YXg%20Ige2CeGwKWhMZlGeyM2l0UMscAAPnASOxksl7qj0clnq9bDBQDQIOwYL40SBirosQAOAAMDI2ITy%20LgMHswDQADpml4aFiFOguVQqggdK5sGD8Vsars8ay7ISQMTSfKFXBpmg5os1Qqufr3oI1lLbKIQj0Xq9gPw4O44aYaOZLMzJZaFRD4Y7oVzHC5XOzOTzOnzzSaxBsEvEgA)

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth explanation. Im slowly trying to figure out TS... Really well explained.

My interceptor has the property hook as you said, but im a little confused how you're reversing it. Could you explain how you approach this?

Comment: @EliasMarcoLip If you want to figure out what a variable needs to be, look at how you are using it.  Presumably the interceptors object from axios has lots of methods, but the only capability that we need here is for executing this line: `interceptors.hook(this.instance);`  We know the type of argument that we give it and we know that we don't need any returned value.  If you define your arguments to the minimal interface that you need it makes your code more flexible because you could pass in any object with a `hook` method as your interceptor.  That's just a general OOP principle/idea.